# Can I create a .Z file with gzip?

Tags: linux, compression, gzip, lempel-ziv-76

I need to create a .Z (compress) file as the receiver is expecting to read it with uncompress utility. But I don't have the possibility to install compress package on my Linux host.

Is there a way to get the compressed .Z file (using adaptive Lempel-Ziv coding) with gzip command?

Comment: Why not just install the compress command? It should be part of your distro. On opensuse, it's in ncompress.

Comment: Because I'm not granted to install it. I should ask to my admin but formerly it would take time an authorization. If I have an alternative solution with gzip I would prefer, if not I would raise a request to install the package.

Comment: gzip does not do .Z files. If you have a C compiler, then I suggest you download the source from sourceforge and install it locally. If not, then raise the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. gzip cannot compress to the .Z format.

Download the [source code for compress](https://github.com/vapier/ncompress), compile it, and use it. (You do not need to have it installed on your system.)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:

- `scp` your file to a system that is less hobbled and compress it there
- use a docker image

You can run the `fedora` docker image like this with a *"bind mount"* so that the files on your local host are visible in `/data` in the container:

```
docker run -it --rm -v "$(pwd)":/data fedora
```

Then, inside the container, run:

```
yum install ncompress
compress SOMEFILE
exit
```

and your container will be removed and nothing will have been installed on your local host and you'll have a lovely, compressed `SOMEFILE.Z`

Comment: I'd expect that the OP can't upload/copy arbitrary files to that machine. Otherwise it seems a bit of a non-issue. On something like Debian, I'd just download the appropriate .deb and grab the binary from there. Or, like you said, just compress it somewhere else.